# Open multiple document in one windows acrobat reader 9

Tags: windows, adobe-reader

I saw that AR9 under Linux offers tabbing (opening several files under the same window with each having a tab of its own).

Does such an option exist for the Windows version?

(I'm using WinXP with AR 9.2.0)

Comment: What's the version number of your AR9. The Windows one is at 9.2.0

Comment: My version is 9.2.0

Comment: PDF-Xchange Viewer does that ... and much more: http://www.docu-track.com/home/prod_user/PDF-XChange_Tools/pdfx_viewer

Comment: @Molly - Thanks I'll give it a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this option is available in the Windows version. As I mentioned in my comment I have version 9.2.0 installed and can't find any options or preferences for opening in tabs rather than new windows.

Comment: Is there an option to open all the PDFs under the same window? It used to exist in version 8, but I am not sure about 9.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Acrobat Reader, but [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) is a freeware pdf viewer that opens multiple pdf in tabs.  It seems a bit quicker to open documents than AR as well.

I know it's not a solution to the AR problem, but it is an alternative option...

Comment: this is not an answer to the question (as you know), make this a comment and avoid downvoting.

Comment: I am familiar with Foxit. Thanks, but I find it has several disadvantages.